# Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

The default version of the webbrowser control in a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)
application is 7. I have changed to 9 by the article *[Browser Emulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)*, but how is it possible to use the latest version of the installed Internet Explorer in a webbrowser control?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I saw Veer's answer. I think it's right, but it did not I work for me. Maybe I am using .NET 4 and am using 64x OS so kindly check this.

You may put in setup or check it in start-up of your application:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
    SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(appName);
}

private void SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName)
{
    RegistryKey Regkey = null;
    try
    {
        // For 64 bit machine
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        else  //For 32 bit machine
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

        // If the path is not correct or
        // if the user haven't priviledges to access the registry
        if (Regkey == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed - Address Not found");
            return;
        }

        string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

        // Check if key is already present
        if (FindAppkey == "8000")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required Application Settings Present");
            Regkey.Close();
            return;
        }

        // If a key is not present add the key, Key value 8000 (decimal)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FindAppkey))
            Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)0x1F40), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        // Check for the key after adding
        FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

        if (FindAppkey == "8000")
            MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Applied Successfully");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed, Ref: " + FindAppkey);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed");
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the Registry
        if (Regkey != null)
            Regkey.Close();
    }
}
```

You may find messagebox.show, just for testing.

**Keys are as the following:**

> - **11001 (0x2AF9)** - Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11
>     edge mode, regardless of the `!DOCTYPE` directive.
> - **11000 (0x2AF8)** - Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing
>     standards-based `!DOCTYPE` directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode.
>     Default value for IE11.
> - **10001 (0x2711)**- Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards
>     mode, regardless of the `!DOCTYPE` directive.
> - **10000 (0x2710)**- Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based
>     `!DOCTYPE` directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default
>     value for Internet Explorer 10.
> - **9999 (0x270F)** - Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9
>     Standards mode, regardless of the `!DOCTYPE` directive.
> - **9000 (0x2328)** - Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing
>     standards-based `!DOCTYPE` directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
> - **8888 (0x22B8)** - Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode,
>     regardless of the `!DOCTYPE` directive.
> - **8000 (0x1F40)** - Webpages containing standards-based `!DOCTYPE`
>     directives are displayed in IE8 mode.
> - **7000 (0x1B58)** - Webpages containing standards-based `!DOCTYPE`
>     directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.

*Reference: [MSDN: Internet Feature Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)*

I saw applications like Skype use 10001. I do not know.

**NOTE**

The setup application will change the registry. You may need to add a line in the Manifest File to avoid errors due to permissions of change in registry:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

**UPDATE 1**

This is a class will get the latest version of IE on windows and make changes as should be;

```
public class WebBrowserHelper
{


    public static int GetEmbVersion()
    {
        int ieVer = GetBrowserVersion();

        if (ieVer > 9)
            return ieVer * 1000 + 1;

        if (ieVer > 7)
            return ieVer * 1111;

        return 7000;
    } // End Function GetEmbVersion

    public static void FixBrowserVersion()
    {
        string appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        FixBrowserVersion(appName);
    }

    public static void FixBrowserVersion(string appName)
    {
        FixBrowserVersion(appName, GetEmbVersion());
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion

    // FixBrowserVersion("<YourAppName>", 9000);
    public static void FixBrowserVersion(string appName, int ieVer)
    {
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", appName + ".exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", appName + ".exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", appName + ".vshost.exe", ieVer);
        FixBrowserVersion_Internal("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", appName + ".vshost.exe", ieVer);
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion 

    private static void FixBrowserVersion_Internal(string root, string appName, int ieVer)
    {
        try
        {
            //For 64 bit Machine 
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(root + @"\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appName, ieVer);
            else  //For 32 bit Machine 
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(root + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", appName, ieVer);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // some config will hit access rights exceptions
            // this is why we try with both LOCAL_MACHINE and CURRENT_USER
        }
    } // End Sub FixBrowserVersion_Internal 

    public static int GetBrowserVersion()
    {
        // string strKeyPath = @"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
        string strKeyPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
        string[] ls = new string[] { "svcVersion", "svcUpdateVersion", "Version", "W2kVersion" };

        int maxVer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ls.Length; ++i)
        {
            object objVal = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(strKeyPath, ls[i], "0");
            string strVal = System.Convert.ToString(objVal);
            if (strVal != null)
            {
                int iPos = strVal.IndexOf('.');
                if (iPos > 0)
                    strVal = strVal.Substring(0, iPos);

                int res = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(strVal, out res))
                    maxVer = Math.Max(maxVer, res);
            } // End if (strVal != null)

        } // Next i

        return maxVer;
    } // End Function GetBrowserVersion 


}
```

using of class as followed

```
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion();
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion("SomeAppName");
WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion("SomeAppName",intIeVer);
```

you may face a problem for in comparability of windows 10, may due to your website itself
you may need to add this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" >
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: From MSDN:
"The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of certain portions of the registry on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit and 64-bit registry calls to their respective logical registry views and maps them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit Windows"

You don't need to worry about Wow6432Node

Comment: You can use also HKEY_CURRENT_USER, no need for admin.

Comment: One suggestion: Change `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` to `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Comment: How to set the DWORD with the current installed IE? For example, if I have IE11 installed, my app should create a DWORD with IE11 setting, but if the machine has only IE9, my app should use IE9 settings. How to accomplish that?

Comment: @JobaDiniz kindly check UPDATE 1 will help you :)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!

Comment: sorry a bit out of topic, but,... is this means my windows form app could emulate as it is using other than IEv7 without i need to install it? for instance if i want to emulate IEv8 i dont need to install IEv8 in my laptop didn't I ?

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but for future readers: Your application doesn't need to check if it's running in a 64-bit system or even in a 64-bit process. 64-bit versions of Windows implemented the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector) which will automatically redirect 32-bit apps running on a 64-bit system to the `Wow6432Node` subkey. Your application doesn't need to do anything extra to adapt to this 'new' key.

Comment: A problem arises, when I try to host a WPF-Application in a COM-Interop-DLL. Then `GetExecutingAssembly` raises an exception and I fall back to IE7. Any glue?

Answer (score 62):

Using the values from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation):

```
  int BrowserVer, RegVal;

  // get the installed IE version
  using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
    BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

  // set the appropriate IE version
  if (BrowserVer >= 11)
    RegVal = 11001;
  else if (BrowserVer == 10)
    RegVal = 10001;
  else if (BrowserVer == 9)
    RegVal = 9999;
  else if (BrowserVer == 8)
    RegVal = 8888;
  else
    RegVal = 7000;

  // set the actual key
  using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    if (Key.GetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe") == null)
      Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: Dude, that's a way easier way to get the version... Thanks, this works for me!

Comment: Thanks, nice code except that `CreateSubKey` should be used instead of `OpenSubKey` since OpenSubKey will return null if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Great point! I edited the answer to use CreateSubKey and to only set the value when it has not been set.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. This should be the best answered. Tried the monster solution above but no difference. This approached nailed it. Thanks again!

Comment: anyone not having

"using Microsoft.Win32" and skipped the first answer, need to

"using Microsoft.Win32" and skipped the first answer, need to 

1. add the using or,

2. prefix "Microsoft.Win32." to anything starting with Registry in this great answer1. add the using or,

2. prefix "Microsoft.Win32." to anything starting with Registry in this great answer

Comment: @RooiWillie If the user upgrades the browser on the machine, the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key doesn't get upgraded. Is there any downside to removing the null check? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkNS Well, in that instance, you could do the null check and then a version check before writing it. The logic behind that is simply to avoid the constant writing to the registry, but if you are ok with that, you could simply remove the null check.

Answer (score 22):

```
var appName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

using (var Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true))
    Key.SetValue(appName, 99999, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

According to what I read here ([Controlling WebBrowser Control Compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/):

> ***What Happens if I Set the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Document Mode Value Higher than the IE Version on the Client?***
>
> Obviously, the browser control can only support a document mode that is less than or equal to the IE version installed on the client.   Using the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key works best for enterprise line of business apps where there is a deployed and support version of the browser. **In the case you set the value to a browser mode that is a higher version than the browser version installed on the client, the browser control will choose the highest document mode available.**

The simplest thing is to put a very high decimal number ...

Comment: Note: if you're running a 32bit app on win64, the key that needs editing is under `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft...`. It's auto-redirected in code, but might catch you by surprise if you open regedit.

Comment: short 'n sweet.  For me `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("..`  worked on Win2012 server as admin.

Comment: @bendecko, fot that your application need administrator privilege.

Comment: /!\ don't use this solution /!\ coz it will fallback on IE7 if you use navigate(to a local file) and that your HTML content is in the Intranet zone (ex: using a MOTW to localhost). Using a 99999 would have the same behavior than using 11000. While to resolve the problem i mentionned above you would need 11001.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than changing the RegKey, I was able to put a line in the header of my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Use lastest version of Internet Explorer -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <!-- Insert other header tags here -->
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

See *[Web Browser Control & Specifying the IE Version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)*.

Comment: While this technique works, it doesn't give the same User Agent.
With the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` technique, I get `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; ...`
Whereas, with the `X-UA-Compatible` technique, I get `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; ...`, which Google Analytics detects as a Mobile.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine when all you need is to host a local page (so the user agent string is completely irrelevant).

Answer (score 13):

You can try this [link](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/set-net-webbrowser-control-to-use-latest-version-of-ie/)

```
try
{
    var IEVAlue =  9000; // can be: 9999 , 9000, 8888, 8000, 7000
    var targetApplication = Processes.getCurrentProcessName() + ".exe"; 
    var localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
    var parentKeyLocation = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl";
    var keyName = "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    "opening up Key: {0} at {1}".info(keyName, parentKeyLocation);
    var subKey = localMachine.getOrCreateSubKey(parentKeyLocation,keyName,true);
    subKey.SetValue(targetApplication, IEVAlue,RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    return "all done, now try it on a new process".info();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.log();
    "NOTE: you need to run this under no UAC".info();
}
```

Comment: string ver = (new WebBrowser()).Version.ToString();

Comment: Good , i just wanted to check in registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer` but this way is more simple . thanks

Comment: What is the `Processes.getCurrentProcessName()`? May be `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`?

Comment: What is localMachine.getOrCreateSubKey? Does not exist?

Comment: You can use also HKEY_CURRENT_USER, no need for admin.

Comment: [Here's a nice codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl) which fixes emulation to. Maybe it will help somebody, but I didn't thought it was an answer worth...

Comment: localMachine is in the code - it is a Registry variable set to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Answer (score 4):

Here the method that I usually use and works for me (both for 32 bit and 64 bit applications; ie_emulation can be anyone documented here: *[Internet Feature Controls (B..C), Browser Emulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)*):

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
        {
            // Another application instance is running
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var targetApplication = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName  + ".exe";
            int ie_emulation = 10000;
            try
            {
                string tmp = Properties.Settings.Default.ie_emulation;
                ie_emulation = int.Parse(tmp);
            }
            catch { }
            SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(targetApplication, ie_emulation);

            m_webLoader = new FormMain();

            Application.Run(m_webLoader);
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private static void SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName, int ieval)
    {
        RegistryKey Regkey = null;
        try
        {
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

            // If the path is not correct or
            // if user haven't privileges to access the registry
            if (Regkey == null)
            {
                YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Failed - Registry key Not found");
                return;
            }

            string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            // Check if key is already present
            if (FindAppkey == "" + ieval)
            {
                YukLoggerObj.logInfoMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION already set to " + ieval);
                Regkey.Close();
                return;
            }

            // If a key is not present or different from desired, add/modify the key, key value
            Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)ieval), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            // Check for the key after adding
            FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

            if (FindAppkey == "" + ieval)
                YukLoggerObj.logInfoMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION changed to " + ieval + "; changes will be visible at application restart");
            else
                YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; current value is  " + ieval);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            YukLoggerObj.logWarnMsg("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; " + ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the Registry
            if (Regkey != null)
                Regkey.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to implement Luca's solution, but I had to make a few changes for it to work. My goal was to use D3.js with a Web Browser control for a Windows Forms Application (targeting .NET 2.0). It is working for me now. I hope this can help someone else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClientUI
{
    static class Program
    {
        static Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "jMutex");

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
            {
                // Another application instance is running
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                var targetApplication = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
                int ie_emulation = 11999;
                try
                {
                    string tmp = Properties.Settings.Default.ie_emulation;
                    ie_emulation = int.Parse(tmp);
                }
                catch { }
                SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(targetApplication, ie_emulation);

                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        private static void SetIEVersioneKeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName, int ieval)
        {
            RegistryKey Regkey = null;
            try
            {
                Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

                // If the path is not correct or
                // if user doesn't have privileges to access the registry
                if (Regkey == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Failed - Registry key Not found");
                    return;
                }

                string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

                // Check if key is already present
                if (FindAppkey == ieval.ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION already set to " + ieval);
                    Regkey.Close();
                    return;
                }

                // If key is not present or different from desired, add/modify the key , key value
                Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)ieval), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

                // Check for the key after adding
                FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

                if (FindAppkey == ieval.ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION changed to " + ieval + "; changes will be visible at application restart");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; current value is  " + ieval);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION setting failed; " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close the Registry
                if (Regkey != null) Regkey.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I added a string (ie_emulation) to the project's settings with the value of 11999. This value seems to be working for IE11(11.0.15).

Next, I had to change the permission for my application to allow access to the registry. This can be done by adding a new item to your project (using VS2012). Under the General Items, select Application Manifest File. Change the level from asInvoker to requireAdministrator (as shown below).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

If someone reading this is trying to use D3.js with a webbrowser control, you may have to modify the JSON data to be stored within a variable inside your HTML page because D3.json uses XmlHttpRequest (easier to use with a webserver). After those changes and the above, my windows forms are able to load local HTML files that call D3.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the answers of RooiWillie and MohD
and remember to run your app with administrative right.

```
var appName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

RegistryKey Regkey = null;
try
{
    int BrowserVer, RegVal;

    // get the installed IE version
    using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
        BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

    // set the appropriate IE version
    if (BrowserVer >= 11)
        RegVal = 11001;
    else if (BrowserVer == 10)
        RegVal = 10001;
    else if (BrowserVer == 9)
        RegVal = 9999;
    else if (BrowserVer == 8)
        RegVal = 8888;
    else
        RegVal = 7000;

    //For 64 bit Machine 
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
    else  //For 32 bit Machine 
        Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

    //If the path is not correct or 
    //If user't have priviledges to access registry 
    if (Regkey == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Registry Key for setting IE WebBrowser Rendering Address Not found. Try run the program with administrator's right.");
        return;
    }

    string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

    //Check if key is already present 
    if (FindAppkey == RegVal.ToString())
    {
        Regkey.Close();
        return;
    }

    Regkey.SetValue(appName, RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Registry Key for setting IE WebBrowser Rendering failed to setup");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    //Close the Registry 
    if (Regkey != null)
        Regkey.Close();
}
```

Comment: as people pointed out earlier, using localmachine key register limits app installation by administrator while current user key allow regular users to install the app. the later is more flexible

Answer (score 2):

A better solution in form of [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) is available now. The `WebView2` control uses Microsoft Edge which is based on Chromium as the rendering engine to display the web content in native apps. This control can be used in `Winforms` as well as in `WPF` applications.

To use this in `Winforms`, just install the `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` [NugetPackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2). After that, the `WebView2` will be available to for your application!

[image]

**More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).**

Answer (score 1):

A cheap and easy workaround for it is that you can just put a value which is bigger than 11001 in the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key. Then it takes the latest IE that is available in the system.

Answer (score 1):

just adding the following to your html does the trick no need for registry settigns

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" >
```

Comment: how to add the head meta tag to WebBrowser? I cannot add the registry because my application will be run on User account as default shell (as standalone application web browser)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic Version:

```
Private Sub setRegisterForWebBrowser()

    Dim appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe"
    SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(appName)
End Sub

Private Sub SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(appName As String)
    'ref:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control
    Dim Regkey As RegistryKey = Nothing
    Dim lgValue As Long = 8000
    Dim strValue As Long = lgValue.ToString()

    Try

        'For 64 bit Machine 
        If (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) Then
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", True)
        Else  'For 32 bit Machine 
            Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", True)
        End If


        'If the path Is Not correct Or 
        'If user't have priviledges to access registry 
        If (Regkey Is Nothing) Then

            MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed - Address Not found")
            Return
        End If


        Dim FindAppkey As String = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName))

        'Check if key Is already present 
        If (FindAppkey = strValue) Then

            MessageBox.Show("Required Application Settings Present")
            Regkey.Close()
            Return
        End If


        'If key Is Not present add the key , Kev value 8000-Decimal 
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FindAppkey)) Then
            ' Regkey.SetValue(appName, BitConverter.GetBytes(&H1F40), RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            Regkey.SetValue(appName, lgValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord)

            'check for the key after adding 
            FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName))
        End If

        If (FindAppkey = strValue) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Registre de l'application appliquée avec succès")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Échec du paramètrage du registre, Ref: " + FindAppkey)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception


        MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed")
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally

        'Close the Registry 
        If (Not Regkey Is Nothing) Then
            Regkey.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been posted but here is a current version for dotnet 4.5 above that I use. I recommend to use the default browser emulation respecting doctype

InternetExplorerFeatureControl.Instance.BrowserEmulation = DocumentMode.DefaultRespectDocType;

```
internal class InternetExplorerFeatureControl
{
    private static readonly Lazy<InternetExplorerFeatureControl> LazyInstance = new Lazy<InternetExplorerFeatureControl>(() => new InternetExplorerFeatureControl());
    private const string RegistryLocation = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl";
    private readonly RegistryView _registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && Environment.Is64BitProcess ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
    private readonly string _processName;
    private readonly Version _version;

    #region Feature Control Strings (A)

    private const string FeatureRestrictAboutProtocolIe7 = @"FEATURE_RESTRICT_ABOUT_PROTOCOL_IE7";
    private const string FeatureRestrictAboutProtocol = @"FEATURE_RESTRICT_ABOUT_PROTOCOL";

    #endregion

    #region Feature Control Strings (B)

    private const string FeatureBrowserEmulation = @"FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";

    #endregion

    #region Feature Control Strings (G)

    private const string FeatureGpuRendering = @"FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING";

    #endregion

    #region Feature Control Strings (L)

    private const string FeatureBlockLmzScript = @"FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT";

    #endregion

    internal InternetExplorerFeatureControl()
    {
        _processName = $"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}.exe";
        using (var webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
            _version = webBrowser.Version;
    }

    internal static InternetExplorerFeatureControl Instance => LazyInstance.Value;

    internal RegistryHive RegistryHive { get; set; } = RegistryHive.CurrentUser;

    private int GetFeatureControl(string featureControl)
    {
        using (var currentUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, _registryView))
        {
            using (var key = currentUser.CreateSubKey($"{RegistryLocation}\\{featureControl}", false))
            {
                if (key.GetValue(_processName) is int value)
                {
                    return value;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetFeatureControl(string featureControl, int value)
    {
        using (var currentUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive, _registryView))
        {
            using (var key = currentUser.CreateSubKey($"{RegistryLocation}\\{featureControl}", true))
            {
                key.SetValue(_processName, value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
        }
    }

    #region Internet Feature Controls (A)

    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. When enabled, feature disables the "about:" protocol. For security reasons, applications that host the WebBrowser Control are strongly encouraged to enable this feature.
    /// By default, this feature is enabled for Windows Internet Explorer and disabled for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.To enable this feature using the registry, add the name of your executable file to the following setting.
    /// </summary>
    internal bool AboutProtocolRestriction
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major < 8)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{AboutProtocolRestriction} requires Internet Explorer 8 and Later.");
            var releaseVersion = new Version(8, 0, 6001, 18702);
            return Convert.ToBoolean(GetFeatureControl(_version >= releaseVersion ? FeatureRestrictAboutProtocolIe7 : FeatureRestrictAboutProtocol));
        }
        set
        {
            if (_version.Major < 8)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{AboutProtocolRestriction} requires Internet Explorer 8 and Later.");
            var releaseVersion = new Version(8, 0, 6001, 18702);
            SetFeatureControl(_version >= releaseVersion ? FeatureRestrictAboutProtocolIe7 : FeatureRestrictAboutProtocol, Convert.ToInt16(value));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internet Feature Controls (B)

    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. Defines the default emulation mode for Internet Explorer and supports the following values.
    /// </summary>
    internal DocumentMode BrowserEmulation
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major < 8)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(BrowserEmulation)} requires Internet Explorer 8 and Later.");
            var value = GetFeatureControl(FeatureBrowserEmulation);
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DocumentMode), value))
            {
                return (DocumentMode)value;
            }
            return DocumentMode.NotSet;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_version.Major < 8)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(BrowserEmulation)} requires Internet Explorer 8 and Later.");
            var tmp = value;
            if (value == DocumentMode.DefaultRespectDocType)
                tmp = DefaultRespectDocType;
            else if (value == DocumentMode.DefaultOverrideDocType)
                tmp = DefaultOverrideDocType;
            SetFeatureControl(FeatureBrowserEmulation, (int)tmp);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internet Feature Controls (G)

    /// <summary>
    /// Internet Explorer 9. Enables Internet Explorer to use a graphics processing unit (GPU) to render content. This dramatically improves performance for webpages that are rich in graphics.
    /// By default, this feature is enabled for Internet Explorer and disabled for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.To enable this feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable file to the following setting.
    /// Note: GPU rendering relies heavily on the quality of your video drivers. If you encounter problems running Internet Explorer with GPU rendering enabled, you should verify that your video drivers are up to date and that they support hardware accelerated graphics.
    /// </summary>
    internal bool GpuRendering
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major < 9)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(GpuRendering)} requires Internet Explorer 9 and Later.");
            return Convert.ToBoolean(GetFeatureControl(FeatureGpuRendering));
        }
        set
        {
            if (_version.Major < 9)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(GpuRendering)} requires Internet Explorer 9 and Later.");
            SetFeatureControl(FeatureGpuRendering, Convert.ToInt16(value));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Internet Feature Controls (L)

    /// <summary>
    /// Internet Explorer 7 and later. When enabled, feature allows scripts stored in the Local Machine zone to be run only in webpages loaded from the Local Machine zone or by webpages hosted by sites in the Trusted Sites list. For more information, see Security and Compatibility in Internet Explorer 7.
    /// By default, this feature is enabled for Internet Explorer and disabled for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.To enable this feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable file to the following setting.
    /// </summary>
    internal bool LocalScriptBlocking
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major < 7)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(LocalScriptBlocking)} requires Internet Explorer 7 and Later.");
            return Convert.ToBoolean(GetFeatureControl(FeatureBlockLmzScript));
        }
        set
        {
            if (_version.Major < 7)
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(LocalScriptBlocking)} requires Internet Explorer 7 and Later.");
            SetFeatureControl(FeatureBlockLmzScript, Convert.ToInt16(value));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    private DocumentMode DefaultRespectDocType
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major >= 11)
                return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer11RespectDocType;
            switch (_version.Major)
            {
                case 10:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer10RespectDocType;
                case 9:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer9RespectDocType;
                case 8:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer8RespectDocType;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    private DocumentMode DefaultOverrideDocType
    {
        get
        {
            if (_version.Major >= 11)
                return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer11OverrideDocType;
            switch (_version.Major)
            {
                case 10:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer10OverrideDocType;
                case 9:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer9OverrideDocType;
                case 8:
                    return DocumentMode.InternetExplorer8OverrideDocType;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}

internal enum DocumentMode
{
    NotSet = -1,
    [Description("Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE latest installed version mode.")]
    DefaultRespectDocType,
    [Description("Webpages are displayed in IE latest installed version mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive.  Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive could causes the page to load in Quirks.")]
    DefaultOverrideDocType,
    [Description(
        "Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks."
    )] InternetExplorer11OverrideDocType = 11001,

    [Description(
        "IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11."
    )] InternetExplorer11RespectDocType = 11000,

    [Description(
        "Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive."
    )] InternetExplorer10OverrideDocType = 10001,

    [Description(
        "Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10."
    )] InternetExplorer10RespectDocType = 10000,

    [Description(
        "Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks."
    )] InternetExplorer9OverrideDocType = 9999,

    [Description(
        "Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.\r\n" +
        "Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards - based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode."
    )] InternetExplorer9RespectDocType = 9000,

    [Description(
        "Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks."
    )] InternetExplorer8OverrideDocType = 8888,

    [Description(
        "Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8\r\n" +
        "Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards - based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode."
    )] InternetExplorer8RespectDocType = 8000,

    [Description(
        "Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control."
    )] InternetExplorer7RespectDocType = 7000
}
```

Comment: What to do with it?.. How to use it? What to call and when?

Comment: You call it during first lunch of code if you like. To use 
`code` InternetExplorerFeatureControl.Instance.BrowserEmulation = DocumentMode.DefaultRespectDocType;'

For better understanding where this was pulled you can look at 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ee330720%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Also to add note, this one doesn't require administrator rights to enable. It also will select correct registry based on bitness and sets same restrictions the documentation shows. Such as GPU render needing IE 9 to work

Answer (score 0):

It is best to force the highest mode possible. That can be accomplished by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and it is always good to include the polyfill library in order to support IE:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
```

before any script.