# Execution of an html in webbrowser Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am creating an application in visual studio 2012 which includes a webbrowser element.
In this webbrowser i load a html which i created. in this html i am executing a javascript(
download coordinates from server and adding markers on googlemap) every 5 seconds.
My problem is that when i am running the html file on chrome or other browser it works perfect
but in webbrowser of vbnet it looks like the javascript runs only once and never again.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Webbrowser Element in VS is like a REALLY old version of IE. That might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment above, VS uses a very old version of an IE similar browser. What you are trying to do is not possible with the VS browser because it doesn't support the version of JS you are using.

Comment: You can specify the rendering mode; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control