# C# Webbrowser not loading certain images

Tags: c#, image, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a code that checks for image links and turn them into

```
<img src="link"></img>
```

My problem is, certain images from certain websites do not work. I tried re-uploading them to another image hosting server and they work. But also when I check them on IE they start appearing in my program.

It's not a `CMYK` problem, I think it's more of a compatibility problem or cache related.

I tried changing compatibility mode from IE7 to IE9 but the images still do not load.

Comment: problem may be in IE version. web browser control uses IE7 version by default. so, check it

Comment: According to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/, I'm using IE 9 with IE 7 compatibility view.

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control)?

Comment: I tried changing to IE9 Compatibility mode manually. http://whatismybrowser.com used to show that I had IE7 compatibility before but not anymore (so it's working) But still the images do not load.

Comment: How did you change to IE9 mode? With the registry edit?

Comment: Yes , if you're using x32 application on x64 you need to change those in Wow64node.