# Why am I getting a Google Map JavaScript error in my WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, syntax-error

I'm missing something when trying to add a Google Map to a WordPress theme.  When I use the plugin [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) for WordPress development it throws a JavaScript error of:

```
Script error.
line 0
```

I'm unsure where the issue falls and at the beginning after doing research I thought my issue was when I didn't have `async defer` when calling the Map's API:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

after reading:

[Step 2: Add a map with a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#step_2_add_a_map_with_a_marker)

I researched to resolve what I thought was the issue and I ran across:

- [How to add defer=“defer” tag in plugin javascripts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts)
- [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/how-to-add-defer-defer-tag-in-plugin-javascripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944027/how-do-i-defer-or-async-this-wordpress-javascript-snippet-to-load-lastly-for-fas)
- [Script Loader tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/)

The code for **functions.php**:

```
function call_the_js_files() {  
    if (is_page_template('page-foo.php')) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google_api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AP_KEY&callback=initMap', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
        add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
            if ( 'google_api' !== $handle )
                return $tag;
            return str_replace( ' src', ' async defer src', $tag );
        }, 10, 2 );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google_map', get_template_directory() . '/js/google.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_the_js_files' );
```

The code for **google.js**:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(function initMap() {
        var uluru = {
            lat: 11111111, 
            lng: 222222222
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: uluru
        });
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
           var center = map.getCenter();
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center); 
        });
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

When I view the source I get:

```
<script type='text/javascript' async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY;callback=initMap'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='site/location/for/js/google.js'></script>
```

but I'm still thrown an error with Debug Bar.  Is there something I am missing or doing incorrectly?  I have no issues with rendering the map the only issue I'm experiencing is the JavaScript error.  While in dev my current API settings on Google are set to `None` under restrictions.

When I researched further under `google map script error line 0` I ran across [Google Maps Script error in Onion.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974901/google-maps-script-error-in-onion-js) but I am already running `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in my header.php.

Comment: I think the issue here is your second script runs before google api loads into the page. if you add async, other resources will keep loading concurrently. Also it would be a stupid question but are you adding your scripts in between head and do you have an element with googleMap id?

Comment: Its loaded in the footer and yes im calling the element.  As stated it renders fine but it throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559826/1952287) I ended up targeting the `wp_footer` and included the JavaScript instead of calling it from an external file as that is what is in Google's example.

Here is the code, I hope it can help someone else:

```
function call_the_js_files() {  
    if (is_page_template('page-foo.php')) :
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = {
            lat: 11111111, 
            lng: 222222222
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: uluru
        });
        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
           var center = map.getCenter();
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center); 
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google_api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AP_KEY&callback=initMap', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
        add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
            if ( 'google_api' !== $handle )
                return $tag;
            return str_replace( ' src', ' async defer src', $tag );
        }, 10, 2 );
    endif;
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'call_the_js_files' );
```

Answer (score 1):

change your functions.php to include something like the below.  The google map api has a dependency to your script.

```
<?php

function theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'gmap', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOuR_KEY&callback=initMap', array ('theme_js'), '1.0', true );

    wp_register_script( 'theme_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/hotelloc.js', array(), '1.0', true );



}

add_action('wp_footer', 'theme_js');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think the issue is at

```
( function( $ ) {
$(function initMap() {
```

this is throwing an error because you can't define a function like that. Replace it as

```
( function( $ ) {
    function  initMap(){
    .....
    }
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: No that is not the issue, reference [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress).  The issue seems to appear in the call the map API.