# why JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse does not work?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this javascript result:

```
var layer = '{"type":"polygon", "coordinates": "-34.32982832836202 149.88922119140625, -34.80027235055681 149.80682373046875, -34.74161249883173 150.30120849609375, -33.99802726234876 150.77362060546875, -33.97980872872456 150.27923583984375"}';
```

I checked it against JSONlint.com and was told it is a valid JSON string.

why can't `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` not work.

I'm being told by the console that `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify` are not recognized functions.

Thanks.

## UPDATE 1

ok.  let me try this again.  Sorry, was given bad info.

```
var polygon = new Array();
polygon.push('{"type":"polygon", "coordinates": "-34.32982832836202 149.88922119140625, -34.80027235055681 149.80682373046875, -34.74161249883173 150.30120849609375, -33.99802726234876 150.77362060546875, -33.97980872872456 150.27923583984375"}');

var layer = polygon[0]  //should be of value of string just stored
console.log(layer);  //correctly displays JSON string
console.log(JSON.parse(layer));  //line that errors.
```

this is a portion of the full code below:

```
// This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">
var selectedShape;
var drawingManager;
var names = [];
var polygons = new Array();


function initMap() {


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['circle', 'polygon', 'rectangle']
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        },
        circleOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        },
        rectangleOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        }


    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    //load preset data


    function setJSON(Shape) {
        console.log(Shape.type);
        if (Shape.type === "circle") {
            return '{"type":"'+Shape.type +'", "lat":"'+Shape.getCenter().lat()+'", "lng":"'+Shape.getCenter().lng()+'", "radius":"'+Shape.getRadius()+'"  }';
        }
        if (Shape.type === "rectangle"){
            return '{"type":"' + Shape.type + ', "start":"'+ Shape.getBounds().getNorthEast() +'", "end":"'+ Shape.getBounds().getSouthWest() +'"}';
        }
        if (Shape.type === "polygon"){
            //eturn '{"type":"'+ Shape.type +'"}' + Shape.getPaths();
            vertice = Shape.getPath();
            console.log("vertice count:  " +  vertice.getLength());
            JSON = '{"type":"'+ Shape.type +'", "coordinates": "';
            vertice.forEach(function(xy, i) {
                JSON = JSON + xy.lat() + ' ' + xy.lng() + ', ';
            });

            JSON = JSON.slice(0,-2) + '"}';
            return JSON;
        }

        return 0
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {

        drawingManager.setMap(null);

        var newShape = event.overlay;
        newShape.type = event.type;
        selectedShape = newShape;
        console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));

        if (newShape.type === "circle" || newShape.type === "rectangle") {

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

        }

        if (newShape.type === "polygon") {

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape.getPath(), 'set_at', function(event) {
                // complete functions
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event) {
                // complete functions
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape, 'rightclick', function(event) {
                // Check if click was on a vertex control point
                if (event.vertex === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                deleteMenu.open(map, selectedShape.getPath(), event.vertex);
                console.log('right-click');
            })

        }

        function DeleteMenu() {
            this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
            this.div_.className = 'delete-menu';
            this.div_.innerHTML = 'Delete';

            var menu = this;
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function() {
                menu.removeVertex();
            });
        }
        DeleteMenu.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        DeleteMenu.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            var deleteMenu = this;
            var map = this.getMap();
            this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(this.div_);

            // mousedown anywhere on the map except on the menu div will close the
            // menu.
            this.divListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mousedown', function(e) {
                if (e.target != deleteMenu.div_) {
                    deleteMenu.close();
                }
            }, true);
        };

        DeleteMenu.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(this.divListener_);
            this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);

            // clean up
            this.set('position');
            this.set('path');
            this.set('vertex');
        };

        DeleteMenu.prototype.close = function() {
            this.setMap(null);
        };

        DeleteMenu.prototype.draw = function() {
            var position = this.get('position');
            var projection = this.getProjection();

            if (!position || !projection) {
                return;
            }

            var point = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(position);
            this.div_.style.top = point.y + 'px';
            this.div_.style.left = point.x + 'px';
        };

        DeleteMenu.prototype.open = function(map, path, vertex) {
            this.set('position', path.getAt(vertex));
            this.set('path', path);
            this.set('vertex', vertex);
            this.setMap(map);
            this.draw();
        };

        DeleteMenu.prototype.removeVertex = function() {
            var path = this.get('path');
            var vertex = this.get('vertex');

            if (!path || vertex == undefined) {
                this.close();
                return;
            }

            path.removeAt(vertex);
            this.close();
        };

        var deleteMenu = new DeleteMenu();

    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnClear'), 'click', function(event) {
        selectedShape.setMap(null);
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('save'), 'click', function(event) {
        names.push($('#polyname').val());
        polygons.push(setJSON(selectedShape));
        length = names.length;
        console.log(length);
        console.log("name:  " + names[length-1] + "; polygon:  " + polygons[length-1]);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnrecall'), 'click', function(event) {

        $('#btnClear').click();
        console.log($('#btnLoad').val());
        var namefield = $('#btnLoad').val();
        if (namefield !== undefined){
            var polyid = names.indexOf(namefield);
            if (polyid > -1) {
                var layer = polygons[polyid];
                console.log(layer);
                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(layer)));



            }else {
                alert("no polygon by that name.  Please Try again");
            }
        }else {
            alert("please enter a name to continue.");
        }

    });



}
```

Comment: It indeed works.

Comment: You already have your object as a string with the single quotes. Do you mean to do that?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you using JSON.parse(layer) ?

Comment: I just ran your code from UPDATE1 and it works fine, gives no errors, could you provide details as to what browser you are running it on?

Comment: all of them....I included the library I was given to give you specifics.  The idea was to load the polygon array with a JSON string.  the intent is to re-call the JSON string and parse it into an object for processing.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(layer)));` from what I saw the array `polygons` consists of strings that represent a JSON object, so why would you use `JSON.Stringify(layer)` if it is already a string? Maybe try to use directly `JSON.Parse(layer)`, and it should return you a JSON object. Hope this helps!

Comment: tried that.  stringify was a recommendation to see if it'll "standardize" the string for parsing.

Comment: @arcee123 what do you get if you simply type `console.log(layer)`?

Comment: the JSON string I'm expecting

Comment: I would suggest you to try and use jQuery, then use `$.parseJson()` and see if that fixes your problem!

Comment: same response.  now it says `Uncaught TypeError: $.parseJson is not a function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148250/discussion-between-n-ivanov-and-arcee123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, while putting code in at Update #1 above, another question I had placed in stackoverflow had a direct impact on the reason for this question.

[why am I getting type errors when hovering over map after layers are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851014/why-am-i-getting-type-errors-when-hovering-over-map-after-layers-are-set)

as such, I had a variable I called `JSON` elsewhere in the code.  using `JSON` as a variable overridden all of the global `JSON` directives, which denied access to the `parse` function.

Thanks all guys.

Comment: to systematically prevent such override-bugs in JavaScript it is important to work with naming conventions, like lowerCamelCase. In this case you would name it `json` instead `JSON`
To get a good start see https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-local-variable-names or here on Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/q/921133/3313410

Comment: thanks.  I did update the standards after this question...but +1 for others.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var layer = '{"type":"polygon", "coordinates": "-34.32982832836202 149.88922119140625, -34.80027235055681 149.80682373046875, -34.74161249883173 150.30120849609375, -33.99802726234876 150.77362060546875, -33.97980872872456 150.27923583984375"}';

$(document).ready(function() {
  // here you can directly use it as a string no need of JSON.Stringify();
  $("#string").text(layer);

  // here it is parsed as a JSON and works just fine
  $someVar = JSON.parse(layer);
  $("#object").text($someVar.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="string"></p>
<p id="object"></p>
```

**EDIT:**
Please provide some details on what browser are you using, and maybe provide the exact javascript that is failing? It would be easier then to provide you with an exact answer.

The variable that you have provided in your question is already a string, so you do not need the use of `JSON.Stringify()`. You can use it directly as a string. Otherwise in the code snippet I have managed to use `JSON.Parse()` with no problem. Maybe try and check your code and compare it with the example?
Hope this helps you out

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to parse it. Check here. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146268/json-stringify-and-json-parse-not-working-in-ie9) for browser issue with JSON in IE.

```js
var layer = '{"type":"polygon", "coordinates": "-34.32982832836202 149.88922119140625, -34.80027235055681 149.80682373046875, -34.74161249883173 150.30120849609375, -33.99802726234876 150.77362060546875, -33.97980872872456 150.27923583984375"}';

console.log(JSON.parse(layer));
```