# What is google maps opening in Lite Mode in my embedded WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webbrowser-control

I am wondering why is Google Maps opening in Lite form in my embedded WebBrowser control? Are there any settings that I need to use before I navigate to Maps? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the requirements for Earth-view:

- https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3096703
- https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3032024?rd=1

The default IE-version for the Control seems to be IE7, which  is not compatible with the Earth-view.

Maybe this helps to force the usage of another version:
[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control)