# Keeping a window in a VB.net form

Tags: vb.net, forms, google-chrome

I have a Windows form created with VB.net. I'd like to be able to take another window from my PC by window handle and put it in my form. Is this possible? I see online with techniques like this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrue7CIghIw

You can have forms in forms. Is there an API to do this?

My issue is, that VB.net does not support chrome webbrowser controls. I am loading a webpage and there are compatibility issues, so I have to run it in edge compatibility mode, and even then it is buggy. Putting chrome in my window is the only option.

I want my app to simply launch a Chrome application shortcut, find the window and take it and put it as a child of my form, so it sits inside the form like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbU7X.png

Any clues? Thanks everyone :D

Comment: This SO post might help you add a chrome browser control to winforms .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534843/google-chrome-control-for-net

Comment: The video is about MDI - multi-document interface. Allows you to display child windows (forms) in a parent form. These are not external apps - just forms under one parent. David's link should help - note some of the approaches have been depreciated.

Comment: You can set the WebBrowser control to use the latest version of Internet Explorer, which should fix compability issues. See (C# but easily convertable): http://stackoverflow.com/a/17922508/3740093

Comment: You could add the webkit engine directly.  I don't know if this would solve your issue but try this.  http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The issue is that I'm connecting my computer to my iPhone to remotely send people text messages. However, the website I use to do it (hosted on my iPhone connected over LAN) uses Java to send and retrieve data. The current Win form version occasionally bugs, and 1/50 texts I send fail to get through, it's so annoying because I tab back to games and don't realise I've ignored people.