# Cannot get YouTube video to play inside a Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: winforms, youtube-api, webbrowser-control, youtube-iframe-api

I tried to simpliy assign the following [getting started HTML code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) to the `DocumentText` property of the `WebBrowser` control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives me the following script error at runtime:

[image: JavaScript Error]

It turns out that even the following simplified code produces the same error:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src='https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script></body></html>";
```

So it looks like the `WebBrowser` control is not able to load the iframe-API. What could be the problem here? Or how could I investigate this error further?

Comment: Could you solve your problem? I've same problem as your.

Comment: No I couldn't get it to work with the `WebBrowser` control. I'm now using the Gecko engine instead (Geckofx45 Nuget package).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for WebBrowser. First we have to force WebBrowser running with the latest IE which we have on our machine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34267121/4173702).
Second I have to stream HTML through ASP.NET Web API and Katana like [this](http://hintdesk.com/asp-net-web-api-video-mp4-mjpeg-html-streaming-inside-self-host-app-with-owin-katana/), using WebBrowser to navigate to http://localhost:xxxx/api/xxxx

Setting DocumentText won't work because WebBrowser has many security limitations when loading html locally.

The other simple solution is just use other browser engine like Gecko or CefSharp.

Comment: Only first step of this answer and then webBrowser.Navigate to the embedded link of youtube worked fine for me.