# Not All CSS code works in WebBrowser WPF C#

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf

I have the following HTML and CSS File : https://jsfiddle.net/zhta2z8s/ .
C# code :

```
 Web.Source = new Uri(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/app.html");
```

Where `Web` is a **WebBrowser**. In that WebBrowser border-radius doesn't work for `code` **TAG** and `pre` **TAG**. Why ? What I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `WebBrowser` emulates Internet Explorer (I believe, in your case, IE7), and `border-radius` is only supported on IE9+.

You can check the IE version you're using with [`WebBrowser.Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.version(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Gets the version of Internet Explorer installed.*

---

I found a [blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version#RenderingChallenged) tutorial on how to change the default IE version, but here's the sum up:

- If you **have control over the HTML** you're displaying:

  - If you want the latest possible IE version:

    Add the following tag to your `<head>`:

    ```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    ```
  - If you want a specific IE version

    Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/4824627) with the list of `<meta>` tags.
- If you **don't have control over the HTML**:

  Well, it's complicated. That requires that you edit the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` key in the Windows Registry. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650219/4824627) that teaches exactly how to do that.