# HTML5 on WebBrowser works slower than IE or other browser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I need to show HTML5 pages for WinForm and use component Webbrowser in mode emulation IE10.

When I open any hard page in Webbrowser I see it works slower than IE or other browsers.

For example

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/Cache.html");
        webBrowser.Url = uri;             
        webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

At http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/Cache.html page if set "cache enabled" fps in IE10 > 60 but Webbrowser shows only 15 fps

Registry Mode Emulation IE10 for WebBrowser

```
 private static void Emulation() // IE10
        {
            try
            {
                string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
                string valueName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, false);
                object FindKey = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\"+ keyName,System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,null);
                if (FindKey == null)
                {
                    RegistryKey RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(keyName);
                    RegistryKey.SetValue(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, 10001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registry update error: " + Ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Can't change browser version.");
            }
        }
```

Any advice how to increase performance WebBrowser on WinForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set in the registry to use the latest IE version or Edge. Otherwise the oldest IE7 will be used.
[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I dit it and registry IE10 but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Using http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ do you alse see IE10 in your user agent ?

Comment: I see the same Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0;

Comment: IE 10.0.9200.17609. Can you check working WebBrowser at you comp ?

Comment: In my pc is fast, about 55 fps, using webbrowser control or browser direct. I set it also to IE10 (10001). Using IE11 (11001) is faster, more than 60fps

Comment: Thank you  I'll check application on another pc

Answer (score 2):

What about using another Default Browser?

https://cefsharp.github.io/

Cefsharp is a port of Chromium to .NET! You can use it instead of IE...

Or you could this:

http://www.awesomium.com/#download

Awesomium is a HTML Engine...

Comment: Thank you for cefsharp , i didn't know about it. Awesomium isn't free. How alternative IE I used https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0

Answer (score 0):

When I updated IE from 10 to 11 version performance in component WebBrowser increased to the normal value.