# Can't Open Outlook Mail in WebBrowser (C#, WinForm)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, webbrowser-control

I've built a small WinForm application with a WebBrowser control on it.

it doesn't work with Outlook.com, I'm able to open outlook.com, sign in to my account, but it wouldn't display the mails.
I have Internet Explorer 11 installed on my system.

(here's the app, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogaa1w44har4mnl/ProxyBrowser.exe?dl=0 you can try it to see how it behaves, just input outlook.com and hit Go)

can anyone point out what's the reason and is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: Have you set in the registry, so that WebBrowser control use the latest Version of IE ? Otherwise default is the oldest IE7, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: From that article, you have more choices, like : 10000, 10001, 11000, 11001. I think the latest is Edge.

Comment: [The list of values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)

Comment: that doesn't make a difference, I've updated the program on the above mentioned link