# reCAPTCHA v2 with wpf webbrowser / frame control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, recaptcha

reCAPTCHA has limitation on browser supports however it works on IE without adding any value in compatibility mode. I have been trying multiple things with WPF application which is displaying a webpage hosted inside a Frame (or Web Browser) control. That webpage has Google reCAPTCHA V2 (I'm not a robot). It works fine in all the browsers but inside WPF app it fails to display properly.

Based on following link we need to have specific browser support
https://support.google.com/recaptcha#6262736

I also made sure javascripts are enabled and working fine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well and the only thing I know how to make it work is go into the recaptcha admin console and slide the security preference to the easiest so the webBrowser control can do the image verification at the very least

Update:
Found out basically because the web browser control is IE 7 by default

[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Thanks ESUN. I forgot to update this post here. updating browser emulation using reg Key is solution, You are right. Thanks