# window.close() not working with popup from webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, internet-explorer

Facing an issue with popup opened from .net 2.0 web browser control, where the popup is a calendar widget. On click of any date a parent control is updated with the chosen date and the calendar popup should close.

The date does show up in the parent control but the popup does not close, instead redirects to a login page of the application.

The calendar is opened with the below code:

```
    vWinCal = window.open("", "Calendar", 
"width=250,height=250,status=no, resizable=yes, top=200,left=200");
vWinCal.opener = self;
```

The functionality works fine in windows xp with ie8, but breaks on win8.1 with ie11. Is this because of enhanced IE settings in IE11? Since my code works fine when the application is run as administrator.

Comment: You can try it using difference version of IE. Use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: I have already tried the browser emulation option, did not work

Answer (score 0):

The following bug in ie11 caused the issue:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150430160939/https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810700/subject-ie11-is-losing-cookie-information-and-thus-becoming-detached-from-a-web-application-session

As explained in one of the workaround setting the tabprocgrowth registry key to 0 resolved the issue.