# Website has script errors, appears blank

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

i am trying to visit a website (miksike.ee) in a visual studio c# web browser, but when i test it, a lot of script errors appear and the wabsite looks like this:

[image]

i have done some research and maybe this has something to do with visual studio using an old version of internet explorer, i tried to find some anwsers but couldn't (the website works fine in chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes IE-7 is the default engine for web-controls in .net but you can change it.
The reg. location are depending on machine's architecture

*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]*   (x86)

*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION* (x64)

for quick & dirty fix (**for testing only**) add a binary Double word key giving *name* as binary's name and *value* 9999 or 9000(if u have IE-9) with name of your exe , in-case you have only IE-8 use 8888 or 8000 instead similarly 10001 or 10000 for IE-10 and 11001 or 11000 for IE-11 .Note in the pairs that former value like 9999 will ignore the hinted browser by the page (directives like DOCTYPE ,X-UA-Compatible) and will only use this one

[image]

in case you want for all programs

[image]

for a detailed and production level fix

[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-ie-in-webbrowser-control)
and

[Using the latest IE in web controls](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/442963/make-the-webbrowser-control-give-you-the-installed-ie-version-rendering)

In case your are not going to use it as a web browser but instead just as view to your web application for which you have server access just add below code at beginning of page ,no need of registry.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=**version number here**" />
```

eg

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```