# why i can't open Google Maps API in Internet Explorer. Though it works on Chrome

Tags: html, c++, visual-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I started working on a Windows Forms Appplication that implements Google Maps API V3. The error message is "You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser" (i have IE V.11).

To simplify the matter and rule out problems i only generate a html file with the next code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X - UA - Compatible" content="IE = edge">
<meta name="MonViz" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Google Maps</title>
<style>
#map{
height: 100%;
}
 html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
function initialize () {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -32.7859107, lng: -61.5975163},
zoom: 15,
mapTypeId: 'satellite'
}); 
var ArmstrongCoordenadas = [
{lat: -32.773431, lng: -61.608963},
{lat: -32.775921, lng: -61.594001},
{lat: -32.787867, lng: -61.596914},
{lat: -32.789050, lng: -61.590069},
{lat: -32.794850, lng: -61.591453},
{lat: -32.791174, lng: -61.612879},
{lat: -32.773431, lng: -61.608963}
];
var ArmstrongPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: ArmstrongCoordenadas,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 4
});
ArmstrongPath.setMap(map);
}; 
</script> 
 <script async defer src= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6r2ufoRhiunVrIVkVoOb5nzUjSwEbfkA&callback=initialize " >
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Next i try opening this file with IE and it does not work. Then i try with Chrome and it works!

What i am doing bad?

Comment: works for me in IE11

Comment: Did you check if your browser doesn't use compatibility mode? Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40526335/5140781