# C# WinForm Web Browser Unsupported Browser

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

This is my last resort as I've looked all over this site for a fix, but everything I've tried doesn't work.

**Issue:** I want to navigate to www.espn.com via a webbrowser tool in my winform app, but I am only able to get a degraded version of espn since it tells me I'm using an unsupported browser.

**What I've tried:** I've tried multiple solutions where you change/add a registry key to the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION but it doesn't seem to change anything.

This link is the code I've tried to fix this issue but no such luck.

[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

Anyone have any ideas???

This is my current result:
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has provided any ideas related to this. I know it seems like it should work but it doesn't. Has anyone else tried on their own?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are running your windows forms project in debug mode from visual studio? **Fist** your need to add the BROWSER_EMULATION keys to your registry...a name value pair, where the name is the name of the exe that your project compiles to, and a value (as described here -
[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)) for the version of IE you wish to use (use 11).
here is a snippet from my registry

```
[Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"HelpPane.exe"=dword:00002710
"prevhost.exe"=dword:00001f40
"Fiddler.exe"=dword:0000270f
"XMLViewerHPSF.exe"=dword:00002af8
"sllauncher.exe"=dword:00001f40
```

showing the name value pairs in the registry...

**Second**, you then compile your webforms project to an exe with the name you used in the registry. eg myWBC.exe

Unfortunately, you cannot use the BROWSER_EMULATION key(s) when debugging from VS. You can only test your compiled project.

Regards.

Comment: I've tried the above and no change. I even publish the app and its still pulling back the above screen shot. It seems like every other website is using internet explorer 11 correctly except for espn.. I don't get it.