# Navigate Instagram in web-browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, instagram

I'm currently using the following code to navigate Instagram in web-browser, but it didn't work and displays a blank page:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.instagram.com/");
```

How should I change the code to reach this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information like error message. Try to use some [ScriptErrorsSuppressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx) property and error handling event to get more information about the error

Also try to update your registry keys with the help of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control/25650219#25650219) as the default version of the webbrowser control in a C# Windows Forms application is 7

Comment: actually, there is no error message. but I prevent this using CefSharp(https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki). I think that Instagram block attempts from bots like that.

Answer (score 0):

In c# I did this

I put a button and text box.
Put the URL in the textbox
Made it so it loaded the text in the textbox then hide the textbox with

```
textBox1.Hide();
```