# C# Web Browser Control - Make it Just Like IE

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer

My WinForms project involves a C# web browser control - and I am getting the dreaded scripting error (like this image, different error though) when I visit different webpages:

[image: script error]

I have read, *and done*, all the stuff about updating the browser emulation mode from IE7 to IE9 (or 11) in the windows registry (a la this stuff [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)) and the error still persists.

Now this is really frustrating due to the fact the the web page I am visiting works fine in IE itself, it is just my embedded one that has the error.

In desperation, I renamed my generated exe file "iexplore.exe" and bingo, the app works, with *no scripting errors*.

So this tells me there must be other settings in the registry or somewhere that cause this error, if anyone knows what these are I'd be most grateful if you could share them please!

N.B. I don't want to suppress the errors, I want to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property to true disable the alerts for errors. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also change the IE version used by your WebBrowser as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control), though I recommend doing this in the installer as editing the registry requires admin permissions.

I would also recommend navigating to http://detectmybrowser.com/ from your WinForms browser to make sure that the changes you made to your registry are correct.

Comment: Cheers - however I am not interested in suppressing the errors, I am interested in running the script!  And the changes did take effect, I checked that.

Comment: @Mickl can you provide a page where you get this happens ? It can be any public link where you get the error message.

Comment: What is the exe name of your forms project?

see http://www.cyotek.com/blog/configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-internet-explorer-webbrowser-control

Embed websites will assume the IE Emulation Mode of the top Window in MSIE browsers and WBC apps.

you must set that value to 11001.

Comment: @robert, sorry, I don't have an example that is publicly available, which I know exhibits this behaviour for sure.

Comment: @RobParsons - the IE emulation mode is set to 11001.

Comment: @Mickl, unfortunately I don't think there's much I can do to help if I can't reproduce it. One last thing though you did check the console of IE for errors right ?