# Loading jQuery in a C# windows form application

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio

I'm making a Windows Form application that makes use of the browser tool. The browser does not connect to the internet and is only used to load local HTML content.

It's loading HTML CSS and JavaScript fine, but It cant seem to recognise jQuery. Is there a simple way for MVS to recognise jQuery as a script? All of the errors are related to it not understanding jQuery methods.

Comment: are you loading/referencing jQuery from your local filesystem by using the `<script>` tag?

Comment: @Mobigital Yes I am.

Comment: you might get more traction if uploaded some code and page examples, perhaps a downsized page and code sample that could actually be built.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is supported form internet Explorer: 9+

when you use WebBrowserControl you get browser emulator ie 7,

change your regEdit key according with [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)