# JSON stringify returning null (C# WebBrowser control)

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am trying to get a string representation of my JSON object back to my C# application, but every time I use `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`, it returns `null` to my application. I am using a `WebBrowser` control.

Page is set up like this:

```
var myObj = { "foo": [] }
// Push data into it

function getMyObj() {
    return JSON.stringify(myObj);
}
```

In my C# code I have this:

```
 string bar = myWebBrowser.MainBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("getMyObj").ToString();
```

However, after invoking the method, it returns `null`. I even tried putting an `alert` in the JavaScript page where I call the `getMyObj()` function inside the `alert`, but the alert never comes up.

Is it a `WebBrowser` control issue? JSON should be supported, the browser is using IE11.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What if you `console.log(myObj)` just before stringifying it?

Comment: If I test it in a web browser such as IE, Firefox, or Chrome, it prints out the data inside the object. In the application, `console.log(myObj)` doesn't appear in the console so I get no output.

Comment: yeah but what does the data look like? Is it valid? Is it "stringifyable"?

Comment: I see an object with an array of data. It looks valid. When I stringify it in IE, Firefox, or Chrome: `{"data": [{"field1": "value"},{"field1": "value"}]}`. But nothing in the C# application.

Answer (score 1):

I used the meta tag to get around this.  Apparently WebBrowser Control defaults to IE7.  There are registry settings you can change to correct this but I did not want to modify users registry settings.

This question helped me get to the solution:  [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' >
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script>
    var myObj = { "foo": [] }
    // Push data into it

    function getMyObj() {
        return JSON.stringify(myObj);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!