# Requested registry access is not allowed C# window app

Tags: c#, windows, google-maps, registry, manifest

I am creating a window app in which i want to show map to the user, but unfortunately i was getting the error that

> you are using a browser that is not supported by google maps

so i googled the problem and find a solution from stackoverflow

[here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

i added a manifest file into the project which look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <!--<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" 
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">-->
         <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
         <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
             <security>
                 <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                     <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
                     <!--<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />-->
                 </requestedPrivileges>
                 <applicationRequestMinimum>
                     <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
                     <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
                 </applicationRequestMinimum>
             </security>
         </trustInfo>
         <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
             <application>
             </application>
         </compatibility>
     <!--</assembly>-->
</asmv1:assembly>
```

and my page load

```
private void ViewMap_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
    SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(appName);
}
```

> but i am getting the error of Requested registry access is not
>   allowed.

`Regkey=Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);`

on the above line

i have windows 7 64 bit operating system,

what could be the possible solution?

Comment: have you tried to launch your app as administrator?

Comment: we don't have administrator rights

Comment: You'll have to get them. i dont think one can modify the LocalMachine hive without administrator rights

Comment: ok then it is impossible to for us to do with this example?