# Embed modern version of IE

Tags: excel, vba, activex

Using Excel 2010 the default ActiveX web browser (Developer > Insert > ActiveX Controls > More Controls > Microsoft Web Browser) is some horrific version of IE from way back when.

Is there any way to embed a more recent version e.g. IE10 or 11?

I have 10 installed, so the default installation doesn't seem to make a difference.

For clarity: I'd like a VBA automatible (i.e. Microsoft) modern browser as an embedded object in a worksheet. Is this possible?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control), its C# but the registry settings are obviously universal.

Comment: I dont think so that we can do that, [See This MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508(v=vs.85).aspx)