# WPF WebBrowser control is not rendering my site

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have written an application which loads a website and invokes a click event on certain buttons.

Im using the WPF WebBrowser control and attaching to the LoadCompleted event.

```
var Document = this.MyBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
var InputTags = Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

foreach (HtmlElement tag in InputTags)
{
    if (tag.Name == "commit" && tag.GetAttribute("value") == "Activate")
    {
        tag.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on most pages, however it seems the WebBrowser control is not a fully compliant browser and does not render all websites correctly.

On one site im just getting a few images and a grey background. Looking at the source it hasnt loaded most of the page.

The page renders fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Any other browsers i can use that will give me the same functionality that im using in my code example above?

The user agent of the control is reported as:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0; Zoom 3.6.0; wbx 1.0.0)

This was marked as a duplicate. Upgrading the browser to use IE11 emulation didnt resolve the issue.

Comment: @mjwills Ive updated the question with the user agent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

Comment: @mjwills That didnt fix my problem

Comment: @mjwills The user agent remains the same. If i go to https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ it says im using IE11

Comment: I would recommend to switch to some more advanced control, e.g. CefSharp

Comment: @mjwills Well it is. Here is a screenshot showing the browser is 11 and the same user agent string. https://imgur.com/nxutWOu

Comment: @mjwills No its not intranet and i dont have control over the source. Yes ive set the registry string but even without the registry string the Browser still reports as 11.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, my mistake, there was a typo in my executable name the registry. It is now reporting the updated user agent and correctly displaying the page. Thanks.