# C# Webbrowser could write different html file depending on the IE version?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, internet-explorer

My program is appending some HTML elements from a template HTML file by user's actions.

```
string currDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string targetURL = String.Format("file:///{0}/Resources/question_template.html", currDir);
web.Navigate(targetURL);
web.DocumentCompleted += Web_DocumentCompleted;

// writing user's selections into a html file as table.
private static void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    GenerateQuizForTypeA(MainWindow.VM.lstPartA_Words);
    ...
    File.WriteAllText(@"Resources\bob_output.html", web.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(web.Document.Encoding));
}
```

And the weird point is the HTML files are generated totally differently depending on the environments.
What I've understood so far is that C# WinForms webbrowser is based on IE7 rendering engine unless you change the registry value. (like this : [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control))

but This is not about rendering problem. I didn't expect two different HTML files could be created via same exe file.
I used webbrowser's **HtmlElement, web.Document.CreateElement, SetAttribute**

Please refer to both screenshots.
both programs were built in envB and using **.net Framework 3.5, WPF(but currently using WinForms webbrowser with WindowFormsIntegration)**

**(envA) Windows7 64bit, IE8**
Additionally, all elements are turned into upper cases plus it gets rid of double quotations. link: http://softinus.com/files/bob/bob_output_IE8.html
[image: with IE8]

**(envB) Windows10 64bit, IE11**
link : http://softinus.com/files/bob/bob_output_IE11.html
[image: IE11]