# Google Maps embedded in C# WebBrowser Control shows no Zoom/Satellite Buttons

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have Google Maps embedded in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control. Up until recently it worked fine. But now the map type buttons (roadmap, satellite, etc) and zoom buttons are not displayed anymore:

[image]

Opening the same HTML file directly in IE11 works without a problem ([here](https://rawgit.com/nharrer/gmap-dotnet-example/master/MapTest/maptest.html)).

I am doing following to force the embedded IE not to use compatibility mode:

- Setting the IE emulation mode for the application in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to `2af8`.
- using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` in the `<head>` of the HTML.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2. A small example project to reproduce the problem is here: https://github.com/nharrer/gmap-dotnet-example

Here is part of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testpage</title>

    ....
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: { lat: 48.2081743, lng: 16.37381890000006 }
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 48.2081743, lng: 16.37381890000006 },
                map: map,
                title: 'Mark1!'
            });

            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: 50.2081743, lng: 12.37381890000006 },
                map: map,
                title: 'Mark2!'
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAR1yYbZk62bSF0-QWNfVm5FWE_Jpv-ExA&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the c# code that sets the compatibility registry values and initializes the WebBrowser control:

```
public TestForm()
        {
            FixBrowserEmulation();

            InitializeComponent();

            bool designTime = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
            if (!designTime) {
                mapBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;

                string docFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "maptest.html");
                string documentText = File.ReadAllText(docFile);
                mapBrowser.DocumentText = documentText;
            }
        }

        // see: 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control
        // https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/a-brief-guide-to-feature_browser_emulation/
        private static void FixBrowserEmulation()
        {
            var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";

            // 11000 (0x2AF8) - Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed 
            // in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
            int? mode = 0x2AF8;

            try {
                const string regpath = @"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
                using (RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(regpath)) {
                    if (regkey == null) {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error: Can not access: " + @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\" + regpath);
                        return;
                    }

                    var currentMode = regkey.GetValue(appName) as int?;
                    if (currentMode == mode) {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Info: FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION is correct.");
                        return;
                    }

                    regkey.SetValue(appName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

                    currentMode = regkey.GetValue(appName) as int?;
                    if (currentMode == mode) {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Info: FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION set to " + currentMode);
                    } else {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Info: FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION modification failed. Current value: " + currentMode);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

***Update 2022-06-23:* While this question might be of interest for some, it is nowadays recommended to avoid System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and switch to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) for Google Maps. WebView2 uses Edge as rendering engine. I think Google Maps doesn't even work in the IE based WebBrowser control anymore.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be too late but if anyone stumbled upon mentioned issue where zoom and street view controls dissappeared, make sure that you have `AllowNavigation` property of `WebBrowser` control set to `True`. So in this case you should do

```
mapBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Not too late at all. I ended up overlaying c# controls for zooming and the satellite-toggle. Now, I can finally remove that hack. The map works like it used to with AllowNavigation  set to true. Thank you!!