# How do I display a React App in a .NET WinForm application?

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, winforms

I have a .NET 4.6.1 WinForm application. I want to display a react app inside a browser component.

I can display most web pages in the browser without error, but when I navigate to a react app I get an error.

I've been able to do it using the "dotnetbrowser" library developed by "teamdev" which implements Chromium in the WinForm.

Questions:
Why does the browser component throw errors when navigating to a react app?

Should I be attempting to get Chromium to work in the WinForm browser?

Comment: The WinForms browser is an extremely old version of Internet Explorer. I'm not surprised, at all, that ReactJs doesn't work there

Comment: You may want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using that library (dotnetbrowser)? If you are using `WebBrowser` control, It is actually Internet Explorer. On this case, you should add meta tag to page on header like

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

to change rendering mode of internet explorer to force most recent version of it.

or try other libraries, like [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). and open dev tool, see what error happend.

Chromium based webview controls should contain itself chrome; I think you don't need to download standalone chrome.