# C# - Webbrowser can't handle a url the way IE does

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have [this url](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&eotf=1&sl=en&tl=ar&q=Hey!%20l'm%20all%20packed%20and%20ready%20to%20go.%0A%0A%0A%20That%20is%20right.%20Daddy%20and%20Uncle%20Joey%20are%20going%20on%20a%20trip%20today.%0A%0A%0A%20We%20are%20going%20to%20a%20conference%20in%20Barbados.%0D%0ARight%3F%20Can%20you%20say%2C%20''Barbados''%3F%0A%0A%0A%20Barbados.%0A%0A%0A%20Okay.%20l've%20gotta%20say%2C%20it%20means%20so%20much%20to%20me%20that%20you%20guys%20are%20coming...%0A%0A%0A%20...all%20the%20way%20over%20there%20to%20hear%20me%20give%20my%20speech.%0A%0A%0A%20And%20l%20have%20a%20surprise.%0D%0Al%20had%20to%20pull%20some%20strings...%0A%0A%0A%20...but%20l%20was%20able%20to%20get%20everyone%20passes%20to%20the%20entire%20conference.%20That%20is%20right!%0A%0A%0A%20These%20babies%20will%20get%20you%20into%20all%20the%20paleontology%20lectures%20and%20seminars.%0A%0A%0A%20Do%20you%20have%20anything%20that%20will%20get%20us%20out%20of%20them%3F%0A%0A%0A%20We%20are%20excited%20to%20hear%20the%20speech%2C%20but%20the%20rest%20of%20the%20time...). When I nafigate it via IE, it opens google translate and shows the result. But when I use WebBrowser control to navigate it, JS cuases errors and the page load doesn't complete.
Why the control is different than IE, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Probably this: [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control) - or use something better like CefSharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  Alex K. and mjwills. The problem is cuased by the webBrowser control version, and the solution is described here:
[Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)