# How do I resolve "port number should be an integer" error in WPF?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am working on a WPF application that uses the built-in WebBrowser to display Bing Maps. The code can draw polygons on the map, which we are trying to export as KML using the Microsoft.Maps GeoXML module:

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoXml', function () {
       // Pass in the map to export all data into an XML string
       try {
           var xml = Microsoft.Maps.GeoXml.write(map, {
               xmlFormat: Microsoft.Maps.GeoXmlFormat.kml,
               roundLocations: true,
               indentChars: '    '
           });
       }
       catch (e) {
           alert(e)
       }
```

However, this code gives the following error: [Port number should be an integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/970FU.png)

I have looked online and can't find anything about what this error means. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/creating-and-hosting-map-controls/creating-a-basic-map-control) doesn't seem to require any kind of port number, and the map itself (which supposedly uses the same setup) works fine (aside from a few script errors).

**Possibly helpful information**

1. The .htm that we load into the WebBrowser is set up to call methods from a C# helper class. We also sometimes invoke the javascript methods from C#.
2. The actual map functions properly for the most part, but there is a script error when hovering over the dropdown to select the map type. I'm not sure if this points to a problem in our overall setup or not.
3. We have nearly identical javascript in our web project, and get no errors. The only difference is the callbacks to our C# class.

**Attempted Fixes**

I tried to get a stack trace from the error, but it was undefined.

I have used the code at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control) to make sure that the web browser is using the proper version of Internet Explorer. However, I don't get these errors running the .htm in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Take a look at whatever your URL is.  When you see _port number_ it's often in the context of a URL.  For example in http://example.com:8080/this/that, the "8080" (following the colon) is the port number.  My guess is your URL is a little mangled, you've got a colon there, and whatever follows is being interpreted as a bad port number.  Just a guess though

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I only have two URL's in the whole .htm file: 'http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release' and 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'. Since our web project works fine with these same URL's, I don't think they're the problem. Would you happen to know of any way to look at which URL's I'm trying to access? I suppose that should be my next step.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303