# How to handle dialog with "Don’t let this page create more messages"?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a C# program that I've been running in windows 7 fine but now that I upgraded to windows 10 with a newer browser, it has stopped working correctly.

The issue is with handling of dialog boxes.  When it pops up, I just want to close the box.  I used the below code.  If it pops up again, the code executes again to close it.

```
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage");
        if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");
            SendMessage(hwnd, 0xf5, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Now, when more than one box pops up, there will be a checkbox that says "Don’t let this page create more messages".  The above code is unable to close this box.  I'm not sure what I am missing.

I'm not even sure why this error pops up in the first place.  If I intervene and manually click the button on the webpage, I don't get the popup usually.  But that is another issue.

Comment: The easiest way is to fix webpage code

Comment: I have no control over the webpage code

Comment: The web browser control used the web engine where it is run. Perhaps the Win7 and Win10 do behave differently, you could try to setup the control to use a specific browser/compatibility mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use latest version of Internet Explorer in the webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/use-latest-version-of-internet-explorer-in-the-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Yes I am aware of the browser emulation setting and that is something I may end up doing.  However, eventually that will become an issue as webpages get newer.  For now, I'm looking to see if there is a way to update my code so it can just handle the new type of window.

Comment: If you want to follow the same approach then use `Spy++`, find class of that new window and then just replace `FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage")` to the appropriate `FindWindow(<Class>, <Caption>)`.

Comment: I should clarify.  The stuff later in the code runs.  Therefore, I believe FindWindow works as I assume the program would crash if hwnd was null.  Therefore, I am assuming the SendMessage line is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you attach the picture of the window with checkbox? I don't have Win10 near me right now to check it myself.

Comment: @eng3 if `FindWindow` works fine, does the `FindWindowEx` work fine as well? Can you check if `hwnd != IntPtr.Zero` before the `SendMessage`?

Comment: Here is an example of the checkbox: https://www.brokenbrowser.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/01_alert_with_checkbox.png   I'll check and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just send `WM_CLOSE` message to the window instead of emulating click on the OK button:

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage");
if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x10, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```