# Atlassian account logon through WebBrowser control in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I m wondering how to log on Atlassian account in WebBrowser control.

1. Create new WinForms application in Visual Studio.
2. Place WebBrowser control on main form.
3. Set URL property of control as "https://id.atlassian.com/login"
4. Run application. You will see this screen.
   [image]
5. Then enter valid credentials for Atlassian account.
6. See this error message below.
   [image]

How to overcome this problem? Thank you.

P.S. I m, of course, aware that standard WebBrowser component uses very outdated IE by default. I properly updated registry to ensure that IE11 is loaded into control.

Comment: That site doesn't work with IE11. It needs something that supports [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Comment: I tried on `IE 11.1217.16299.0` and it worked well. Same for web browser control. Make sure your registry settings are correct.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei There's a very good chance that the OP has `v. 11.0.9600.17416`. If this is the IE11 version in use, no joy.

Comment: @Boris, Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34267121/2501044

Comment: Jimi, Reza Aghaei, @Golda.thank you for hints. Especially, I m aware on proper registry settings for WebBrowser control and have them as a part of my application. I will double check registry and retry. So far, I can see that it is configured to use IE11 but does not work.

Comment: I double checked that "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" section for my application is equal to 11001 on my system, which corresponds to IE11.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue [JRACLOUD-71973](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-71973) in official bug tracking of Atlassian indicating that it is general problem not only with Confluence but with JIRA also. I suppose that Atlassian cloud products do not work with IE 11 anymore in principle, be it full IE application or just WebBrowser control. It is astonishing that Atlassian actually dropped support of quite popular web browser. Perhaps, we must monitor this issue to know when / if this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Sad but true and inevitable. You could try the new [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) control, if your project can meet the client-side OS requirements for this control. There are other options like CEF which I'm sure you're aware of. When we faced a similar challenge though, we just decided to switch to Electron.

Comment: @noseratio, Thank you for a valuable hint. It might be a way to try. Although, our goal is ultimately not a visual control but rather hidden browser to crawl the content. Embedded Chrome and Firefox are too heavy weight components with plenty deployment side effects. WebBrowser control worked nicely until recently. It is a pity that Atlassian deprecated it.