# How to change the top-left icon on a ShDocVW C# window

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw, shdocvw.internetexplorer

First of all, I am a real newbie to programming in Visual Studio. That being said, I have created a small program that pops up an Internet Explorer window; I now want to replace the Internet Explorer icon in the top-left corner with the project's icon.

Currently, I am opening the window in C#, using the `ShDocVw` object:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        {      
                AddressBar = false,
                MenuBar = false,
                StatusBar = false,
                ToolBar = 0,
                Visible = true,
                Height = 768
            };

            IE.Navigate2("http://someURL/page.aspx");

        }
```

What I want to replace is the IE icon in the top-left corner (see included picture). The icon is in my project as a resource, and appears on the .exe.

[Screen capture of IE header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7okOp.png)

Is there a way to change the browser icon here?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the [SHDocVw InternetExplorer Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/shdocvw.internetexplorer?view=dynamics-usd-3) and test it on my side, it seems that there is no way to change the IE window icon on the left via the SHDocVw library.

From your description, I suggest you could try to create a WPF or Windows Forms application, then use the [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) or [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/gettingstarted) control to display the web content. In this scenario, you could add the custom icon for the WPF or Windows Forms window. screenshot like this:

[image]

About how to set the window icon, please refer to the following methods:

- To the WPF application, try to use the following code (set the Icon property):

  ```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
          Icon="favicon.ico"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
      <Grid>

      </Grid>
  </Window>
  ```

  More detail information, please check [Setting the application icon in WPF](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/setting-the-application-icon-in-wpf-xaml/)
- To the Windows Form application.

  Right click the **Form**, in the **Properties** , it contains the Icon property, click the `...` button to select icon.

  [image]

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv !  Thanks for your answer.  However, I encountered a small problem with the solution you are proposing.  The project I must build uses the Windows 10 1607 version, and Microsoft Edge isn't an option.  I really need the solution to use an Internet Explorer control.  Do you have any ideas that would involve IE ?

Comment: You could try to use the [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) in the Windows Form application. Here are some resource, you can check them: [link1](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922308/)